# searching csv columns and inserting into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

I am developing a cron job that read a configuration file that has some configurations in json format, and also i have a csv file from which i have to insert the data into mysql tanble
I have completed its first part that is reading configuration file and reading csv file
now the problem is I have to search in the csv for the mysql columns that are in the configuration file and then if found matching column in csv then have to insert the values from that column into mysql table.
I am stuck with this portion and need some help to finish this.
this is the sample configuration file, i have to search for source in csv and the have to put it into detination column of csv.

```
"matchingField": [
            {
                "source": "ProductLongDescription",
                "detination": "Description"
            },
            {
                "source": "ExtraTextOne",
                "detination": "EventDate"
            },
            {
                "source": "ExtraTextTwo",
                "detination": "EventTime"
            },
            {
                "source": "ExtraTextThree",
                "detination": "LocationInfo"
            },
            {
                "source": "Zupid",
                "detination": "Unique_ID"
            },
            {
                "source": "ProductName",
                "detination": "Title"
            },
            {
                "source": "ProductPrice",
                "detination": "Price"
            },
            {
                "source": "MerchantProductCategory",
                "detination": "Category"
            },
            {
                "source": "ImageMediumURL",
                "detination": "ExternalImageUrl"
            },
            {
                "source": "ProductManufacturerBrand",
                "detination": "LocationName"
            },
            {
                "source": "ZanoxProductLink",
                "detination": "RedirectLink"
            },
            {
                "source": "TermsOfContract",
                "detination": "sittingType"
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Could you store the entire csv file into an array and then search the array?

Comment: Ever considered using something like LESS to do this? http://lesscss.org/

Comment: can you please send me some helping code?

Comment: Please post some sample data from the config file and the CSV file. Without that at best you'll get something vague as a response.

Comment: can you please check it now i have updated it

Comment: please check the question now, I have modified it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the solution by myself :). first make two arrays for source columns and destination columns, then make a array for csv header columns, and then search for the header column value in source array and if match found then create a query that contains destination column name and its corresponding value from csv. may b i am not explaining the code well but this solves my problem.

```
while ( ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, $columnDelimiter) ) !== FALSE )
{
    $number_of_fields = count($data);
    if ($current_row == 1)
    {
    //Header line
        for ($c=0; $c < $number_of_fields; $c++)
        {
            $header_array[$c] = $data[$c];
        }
    }
    else
    {
    //Data line
        $sql_str = '';
        for ($c=0; $c < $number_of_fields; $c++)
        {
            if($key = array_search($header_array[$c],$source_arr)){
                $sql_str .= $dest_arr[$key]." = '".$data[$c]."',";
             }
        }
        $sql_str = "INSERT INTO $destinationTable SET ".trim($sql_str,',');
        mysql_query($sql_str);
    }
    $current_row++;
}
```